# how to send consecutive messages from httphandler using json,ajax,jquery

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

I am trying to send two consecutive messages from httphandler file to client using JSON,AJAX and JQUERY. Howerver only the second message is displayed . What could be the reson? How do you display both the messages?

### .ASHX

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class Gen_BLL : IHttpHandler {
  public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
string ename = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Message1..");
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
context.Response.Write(ename);

ename = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Message2..");
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
context.Response.Write(ename);
```

}

```
public bool IsReusable {
get {return false;}
```

}

```
}
```

### .JS file:

```
function funGenAst(usro){
 $.ajax({
type: "GET",    
url: "Gen_BLL.ashx",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: { "uso": usro },
dataType: "json",
success: OnComplete,        
error: OnFail
});
 return false;
}

function OnComplete(result) {
  alert(result);
}

function OnFail(result){
  alert("fail...');
}
```

Only one alert is displayed, ie "Message2.." . "Message1.." alert is not popped up at all. How do you get to alert both messages one after the other?

Thanks
bsc

Comment: you are clearing response `context.Response.Clear();` before sending second message, while the response is not yet flushed.

Answer (score 0):

You simple can not do that.

There is a protocol of http communication, and this is break it, from the moment you send some header and some content, there is not prediction to clear the header, and send a second (or new) message.

About Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP): http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec1.html

Alternative way: Merge your message to one response, or after you receive the first message, make new request to get the second one.